# Putting a for loop result into Data frame

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to create a list out of the result from a for loop in R.
Then I want to use cbind to add the list into the dataframe.
When I run this code, it does not work.
Can you please help?

```
GenSpc <- list()

for(i in 1:68) {

paste(NewtableAllLoci$host_genus[i], NewtableAllLoci$host_species[i], collapse = " ")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not assigned anything to the target list `GenSpc`. To get want you want, do:

```
GenSpc <- rep(0, nrow(NewtableAllLoci))
for(i in 1:nrow(NewtableAllLoci)) {
  GenSpc[i] <- paste(NewtableAllLoci$host_genus[i], NewtableAllLoci$host_species[i], collapse = " ")
}
D <- cbind(NewtableAllLoci, GenSpc)
```

Comment: I want to add the GenSpc list I created as a new column in the table NewtableAllLoci. How can I do it?

Comment: Why you are using a list? I edited my post. Now it should do want you want. Please accept the answer, if it fulfill your requirements :)